# Facebook API How To Get All Pages I Like Without Pagination

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If I like more than 100 pages/things, FB.API('me/likes') returns 99 items and a link to the next paging.

Is it possible to get ALL without the pagination?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need this using what technology? Java? PHP? or Rails? or What? if you inform me, I can answer you

Comment: I'm currently trying things so I'm using JS SDK only, but in the future I might use PHP to connect to database

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried `/me/likes?limit=999` ? 
You may still need to paginate, but you should be able to get more than 99 items in a single call

Comment: For some reasons, I thought it was paginated, but actually it wasn't! I had liked 107 pages, but for some reasons only 99 were returned. When I liked 1 new page, the array returned was 100, so it worked actually. Just wondering why the returned array doesn't match the number of pages I actually like?

Comment: FYI, the unofficial max limit is 5000 results according to [this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/): "the maximum number of results we will fetch before running the visibility checks is 5,000."

Comment: The reason why you're not seeing all items is because FB fetches the limit number of items (if there is that many items) and then removes items that aren't visible to the API user making the request, therefore lowering the final result count.

See more here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

Answer (score 0):

Use FQL:

```
$fql = "SELECT page_id from page_fan where uid = me())";
$pages_i_liked = $facebook->api(array(
                  'method'=> 'fql.query',
                  'access_token' => $access_token,
                  'query'=> $fql,
                  ));

print_r($pages_i_liked);
```

Comment: As of August 2016 FQL is no longer available. source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Answer (score 0):

Get All facebook pages of a user using facebook api

```
required permissions: manage pages

type: GET

url: https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts

param: access_token
```

responce of the above request like this

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "category": "Book",
        "name": "Mind blowing books",
        "access_token": "CAACEdEose0cBAFRU2j0rGgNxBcJvU0pkZCpDbI7rZCJNmO2cZAfZBXoejoZCdTVdKi4gNCyBuu9fPRnWRAwCKrmkPePzKHoE5e46Jz7gRDYe3PM5ECm0ZC5OZB2iWLeEh3OZBgTGfWDmQbbFivwlp5v2umc0CcC9JlTvHsWDnTZCkKIbZAJeD2nOus1ZCCXMqSXHOAZD",
        "perms": [
            "ADMINISTER",
            "EDIT_PROFILE",
            "CREATE_CONTENT",
            "MODERATE_CONTENT",
            "CREATE_ADS",
            "BASIC_ADMIN"
        ],
        "id": "618353601555775"
    }
],
"paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/100000328561058/accounts?access_token=CAACEdEose0cBADKMTNRBl5pjNhw8xsKnQf57XKShV7UlhGyJy67bBZCUKkepl9rELlxqq0I474f8LEPGnt51Mdgs0MMtgTycuUgkOyRnLgVypWVpBd7oKy3LXrrbsQWSdIUZBU4qKHLxSb14TP8ySOaZChLseseYMr1YMLG3qrJiWLuwWJeVz2PeE8TmkkZD&limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=618353601555775"
}
}
```

Post at specific facebook page of a user using facebook api

required permissions: piblish action

```
type: Post

url: https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID}/feed

param: access_token, message
```

this http request will write your message on fb page

**PAGE_ID:** its page id which is in responce of first request

Answer (score 0):

The maximum results limit is 100
"I just noticed this while counting the results and also next page query, if I insert limit 999 for example, the exact results will be shown as 100 and the next link generated by facebook will contain the limit value also 100"

Comment: could you provide some references to uphold this? See [answer]

Comment: I just noticed this in and also next page query, if I insert limit 999 for example, the exact results will be shown as 100 and the next link generated by facebook will contain the limit value also 100

Comment: then please [edit] your answer to explain this! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With this class from Github: [FacebookLikedPagesAPI](https://github.com/abdes-zakari/FacebookLikedPagesAPI) you can get all ID liked pages on Facebook without pagination

```
$access_token = '';// your access token here

$likes=new Likes();
$result=$likes->getAllLikedPages($access_token);
```